# Unitary group and unit circle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

Let $U(n)$ denote the group of complex unitary matrices, let $S^1$ be the unit circle in the complex plane. Then the map

$$f:U(n)\to S^1,\quad f(A)=det(A)$$

is a group homomorphism and a submersion.

It is straight forward to show that $f$ is a group homomorphism. For the second part, we have the derivative of $f$ as follows:

$$df_A(X)=det(A)tr(A^{-1}X)$$

I wonder how can we show that $df_A:T_AU(n)\to T_{f(A)}S^1$ is surjective. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $T_{f(A)} \mathbb S^1$ is one dimensional. To show that $df_A$ is onto, one only needs to find a tangent vector $X$ such that $df_A(X)\neq 0$. (Then the image would be at least one dimensional and thus is onto).

Also, it suffices to check that when $A=I$. (Let $B(t)$ be a curve in $U(n)$ such that $B(0)= I$ and $\dot B(0)=X$. So represent a vector in $T_I U(n)$. Thus $AB(t)$ represent a vector in $T_AU(n)$ and $AX\in T_AU(n)$. Also,

$$f(AB(t)) = f(A) f(B(t)) \Rightarrow df_A(AX) = det(A) df_I(X),$$

so $df_A$ is onto if and only if $df_I$ is.)

We can identify the tangent space as

$$T_AU(n) = \{ X: XA^* + AX^* = 0\}. $$

Let $X$ be a matrix with only nonzero entry at $(1, 1)$, which is $\sqrt{-1}$. This is a tangent vector at identity and $df_I(X) = \sqrt{-1} \neq 0$. Note that the tangent space of $T_I\mathbb S^1$ is isomorphic to $\sqrt{-1}\mathbb R$. Thus $df_IX \neq 0$ and we are done.

Comment: Why is X a tangent vector at identity? Aren't the tangent matrices those with trace 0? Also, is it sufficient to find only one such tangent vector, because then the dimension of the image of the linear map is at least 1? Lastly, why is it sufficient to only check for $A = I$?

Comment: @Ryker: I have just edited the answer. Hope that answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, although I'm still not sure how you got $f(AB) = f(A) f(B) \Rightarrow df_A = det(A) df_I$, and how that's straightforward to see. Care to elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: @Ryker: Please see the edit again. Bests

Comment: Thanks, I thought you were somehow using the product rule, and wasn't sure how exactly. Oh, and you've got a \dot LaTeX generating error there :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(t)=diag(e^{it}, 1,\ldots,1)$. Then $\det(g(t))=e^{it}$, whose derivative at $t=0$ is non zero. Hence the derivative of $\det$ at the identity is non zero, thus surjective (since $\dim S^1=1$).Since $\det$ is an homomorphism, the derivative is suerjective at all points of $U(n)$.