# Question related to tangent space of $U(n)$ at a matrix $g\in U(n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, manifolds, lie-groups

I was working on a homework problem that involved showing that the map $f:U(n)\rightarrow S^1,g\mapsto det(g)$ is a submersion [(which is given here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682732/unitary-group-and-unit-circle/682882#comment1437275_682882) 
And the following question emerged:

*Given $g\in U(n)$ (where $U(n)$ is the group of unitary matrices), and $X\in T_I U(n)$, is it necessarily the case that $gX\in T_g U(n)$?*

I believe this is true, indeed, since $X\in T_I U(n)$, there exists a smooth curve $\lambda:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow U(n)$ such that $\lambda(0)=I$ and $\lambda'(0)=X$. Define $\gamma(t):=g\lambda(t)$. Note that $\gamma$ is still a smooth map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow U(n)$ since $U(n)$ is a group under multiplication.

Furthermore we do have $\gamma(0)=g\cdot \lambda(0)=gI=g$, and 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)=\frac{d}{dt}g\lambda(t) =g\frac{d}{dt}\lambda(t)$$
so it follows that $\gamma'(0)=g\lambda'(0)=gX$.

So we have shown that there exists a smooth curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow U(n)$ such that $\gamma(0)=g$ and $\gamma'(0)=gX$ and so by definition $gX\in T_g U(n)$.

I know that this result seems straightforward but I am not yet comfortable working in this framework so I would appreciate if someone could just quickly glance through my work here and let me know if my reasoning is accurate. Thanks!

Comment: Your reasoning looks fine to me. If you have a Lie group, for each $g\in G$ one can associate the map $L_g:G\rightarrow G$ given by $L_g(h)=gh$ which is smooth. Then the differential of this map is a tangent space isomorphism $dL_g:T_eG\rightarrow T_gG$. What you've done is to calculate how this map acts on a tangent vector; by left multiplication of course! Your proof also shows that this holds for any matrix group.

Comment: @BrianKlatt That makes a lot of sense, and it is a surprisingly nice (and useful) result. Thanks for taking the time to go through it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general idea. If $N$ is a submanifold of a manifold $M$ and a smooth map $f:M\rightarrow M$ satisfies the property that $f(N)\subseteq N$, then for all $x\in N$, $d_xf:T_xM\rightarrow T_{f(x)}M$ restricts to a linear map $T_xN\rightarrow T_{f(x)}N$. In your case, let us take $M=Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $N=U(n)$. Left-multiplication by a fixed $g\in U(n)$ gives $f=L_g$. Since $L_g$ is then a linear automorphism of $Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$, $d_xL_g=L_g$ for all $x\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ if we identify tangent spaces to points in $Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ with $Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. In particular, $d_IL_g=L_g$ restricts to a linear map $T_{I}U(n)\rightarrow T_gU(n)$, so that $gX\in T_gU(n)$ for all $g\in U(n)$ and $X\in T_IU(n)$.